# Interface Segregation Principle involving several classes - how to design properly?

Tags: java, oop

Suppose I have two classes in a system:

```
public class User {
    public int getId() {
        // implementation
    }

    // other methods
}

public class Room {
    public int getId() {
        //implementation
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        int userId = user.getId();
        // uses userId
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Then I realized that the clients(in a different part of the system) of these classes would never need to know about Id. So I applied ISP to extract the interfaces:

```
public interface User {
    // other methods
}

public interface Room {
    void addUser(User user);
    // other methods
}
```

And tried to implement them with ManagedUser and ManagedRoom. Then something unpleasant happened:

```
public class ManagedRoom implements Room {
    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        int userId = user.getId();  // Oops! Cannot get id here.
    }
    // other methods
}
```

So I'm wondering what the proper design is here. And also, have I understood ISP correctly?

Comment: You are saying above _Then I realized that the client of these classes would never need to know about Id_ however in your implementation, ManagedRoom is a client of User, and it needs getId() invalidating your assumption. I suggest you design each class (Room and User) separately instead of coupling them together, or if your design would never use these classes individually then consider nesting them and using outer class (Room) to instantiate inner class (User)

Comment: @Hesham Didn't made it clear that the _clients_ I'm talking about are in another part of the system. Have edited the post.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the clients are located, any Class that calls methods of another class is the _client_ of that class.

Comment: @Hesham So it is. But different parts of the system use different interfaces of User. I want to seperate these uses. I believe the key point is the coupling of the implementations of User and Room. But somehow I don't know how to decouple them. For example, addUser() might make a synchronization with a database. And this operation requires the Id of the User object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that in order to complete entering a particular room only user ID is required. That's at least the only message you pass to the user in your example. 
I propose requiring exactly that rather than the user:

```
interface Room {
    public void enter(String userID);
}
```

Now in order for a concrete user to enter a room you'd have something along the lines:

```
class ManagedUser implements User {

    public void enterRoom(Room room) {
        //provide an ID of some sort to the room
        //particular to ManagedUser world
        room.enter(myID);
    }
}
```

Of course you can have an abstract object User that allows entering abstract Rooms etc. Note that the fact that a concrete room might update the database is irrelevant on this level.

```
class ManagedRoom implements Room {

    public void enter(String userID) {
         //store userID entering this room in whichever way you see fit
    }

}
```

So finally entering a room would look like so:

```
class EnterRoomsGame {

    public void play(User user, Room room) {
        user.enterRoom(room);
    }

}
```

Comment: This way, the ID of the User is hidden. But is there another method, _Room.enter()_, about which a layer above don't care, introduced?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Room having an enter method looks natural to me. Client of the Room is actually the User. So yes, whatever client is telling the User to enter the Room does not care about what a room can do.

Comment: An enter method in a Room class is natural. But what about the userID that should be provided to the method? If I design the interfaces first, I could not know that a user should have an ID.

Comment: You don't, but you'd know that in order to enter the room the guest needs to identify itself. That way the room doesn't care who's actually entering as long as it can provide a string to identify itself (dog, car, user, ...). Each of these objects is absolutely free to store their ID in whichever way they choose, String is what marries the two.

Comment: It could be a valid solution if I'm the one who uses User and Room interfaces. But what if I don't know who will use these interfaces? Someone may call Room.enter() directly, thus bypassing some necessary processing.

Comment: all the processing about entering a room should be inside the room.enter()

Comment: A User may want to change its status. For example, if I want a User to count the number of rooms he had been in, then some processing is bypassed when room.enter() is called directly.

Comment: In your app what does it mean to enter a room? Objects are defined by what they do, what do room and room guest do in the context of entering a room?

Comment: In my app, the Room and the User will add a reference to each other for future uses, and the Room will notify all other Users in it. But even if the User doesn't need to do anything, someone may call Room.enter() with an arbitrary String.

Comment: In which case the client would have been written incorrectly. This should not concern you, same can be said about any operation that involves more than one object.

Comment: Then I would be relived to care much less. But I believe a good API has a low chance of being misused. Could anything help? I know that package-private visibility is a choice. But things can go fairly complicated if the API is implemented in several packages.

Comment: Maybe what's confusing is the name of the message send to Room. Doesn't have to be enter, change it to whatever fits your app. i.e. room.notifyEverybodyPresentThatNewUserEnetered(userID)

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. I finally made User and Room abstract classes with some package-private methods. However, the implementing classes in other packages are still exposed if I export the project into a jar. Wish the coming Java Module System could address the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can define another interface, e.g. `Entity`, as follows:

```
public interface Entity {
    int getId();
    void setId(int id);
}

public interface User extends Entity {
    ...
}

public interface Room extends Entity {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Adding an interface like Entity makes all clients of User aware of the Id, which is not what I expected. And I'm wondering if it is a violation of ISP

Answer (score 0):

accepted

ISP states that:

```
Clients should not be forced to depend on methods that they do not use.
```

ISP relates to important characteristics - cohesion and coupling.
Ideally your components must be highly tailored. It improves code robustness and maintainability.

Enforcing ISP gives you following bonuses:

```
High cohesion - better understandability, robustness
Low coupling - better maintainability, high resistance to changes
```

And, You can study sample ISP at http://www.oodesign.com/interface-segregation-principle.html

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to suggest something without knowing your use-case. But maybe you don't *really* need a generic `addUser()` in the `Room` class. What I mean is, offer methods that are domain specific (have "business meaning") and maybe this problem solves itself.

For example, if this is a MMORPG, you could get away with:

```java
public interface User {
    void leaveNorth();

    void leaveSouth();

    void leaveEast();

    void leaveWest();
}
```

So the `User` and `Room` don't need to reference each other necessarily, at least not in the interface.

As a second approach, different parts of the system do not necessarily need the same "concept" of a `User` and `Room`. This is what Eric Evans called a "Bounded Context". [Here is an article](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) from Martin Fowler about it.

Comment: The action _add_ might be too generic. I could rename it to _invite_, but the problem persists. As for the second approach, I need a way to establish the connections between the shared concepts in different parts of the system. I'm considering a bidirectional map, could it be a good practice?